# AngularJS + Facebook like Directive not working

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, angularjs

Im developing an AngularJs Application wich integrates fb-like in a view. It only works first time and if I refresh the browser also, when I navigate to other view and comeback the plugin does not work.

I have created a directive.

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('fbLike',['$timeout', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    template: "<div class=\"fb-like-box\" data-href=\"{{page}}\" data-width=\"{{width}}\" data-show-faces=\"{{faces}}\" data-height=\"{{height}}\" data-show-border=\"{{border}}\" data-stream=\"{{stream}}\" data-header=\"{{header}}\"></div>",
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var working, _ref, _ref1;

        $scope.page ="https://www.facebook.com/company_name";
        $scope.border = false;
        $scope.height = (_ref = $attrs.fbHeight) != null ? _ref : '260';
        $scope.faces = $attrs.fbFaces != null ? $attrs.fbFaces : 'false';
        $scope.stream = $attrs.fbStream != null ? $attrs.fbStream : 'true';
        $scope.header = $attrs.fbHeader != null ? $attrs.fbHeader : 'false';
        $scope.width = (_ref1 = $attrs.fbWidth) != null ? _ref1 : $element.parent().width()-19;
        $timeout(function () { return typeof FB !== "undefined" && FB !== null ? FB.XFBML.parse($element.parent()[0]): void 0; });
    }
};}]);
```

My view

```
    <script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({

appId: '',
     status: true, // check login status
     cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
     oauth: true

   });

  };

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<div fb-like></div>
```

I was looking for other option but no lucky.

I don't know whats wrong.

Thank you so much

Comment: @rob Hello, yes, I prefered to use Facebook UI. So I include angular-easyfb.js module in the app. Then you put your like btn in the interface <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/yourpage" data-width="460" data-height="260" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false" ></div> hope it's help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best solution I found is add ezfb module to my App, now it's working great.

I fully recommend this module.

```
.config(function ($FBProvider) {
  $FBProvider.setInitParams({
    appId: '386469651480295'
  });  
})
```

There is a demo on Plunker [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eak9VY?p=preview)

[Github Link](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb)

Comment: I tried to use exfb. Seems to still require a refresh to get the plugin to re-render the dynamic path. The plunker seems to show that it should just work (FB like button plugin).

Comment: Specifically:  

    ezfb.init()

In the case that you don't want to(or you can't) configure your FB.init parameters in configuration phase, you may use ezfb.init in run phase. And any ezfb API call will not run until ezfb.init is called.

    angular.module('myApp')

    .run(function (ezfb) {
      ezfb.init({
        // This is my FB app id for plunker demo app
        appId: '386469651480295'
      });  
    });

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something as simple as:

```
directives.directive('fbLike', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: '<div class="fb-like" data-href="{{page}}" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>'
    }
});
```

... and in HTML it's simply:

```
<fb-like />
```

Note also that if you are not hosting the app on the domain specified in the like code, it will not display.  In chrome, you can click network in developer tools and see the result of the ping done from the like widget's JavaScript.

```
<div><span>Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App&#039;s settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App&#039;s domains.</span><script>if (typeof console !=="undefined" && console.log) console.log("Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.");</script></div>
```

Comment: Also note, in your template you escape quotes.  You can avoid that by surrounding the template string with single quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source service [ngFacebook](https://github.com/GoDisco/ngFacebook) check it out